# DoublyLinkedList Confusion

Tags: java, list, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am a little bit confused about the following segment codes, suppose we already have a double linked list head->tail;

```
class DLinkedNode {
  int key;
  int value;
  DLinkedNode pre;
  DLinkedNode post;
}

/**
 *  Always add the new node right after head;
 */
private void addNode(DLinkedNode node){
  node.pre = head;       // line 1
  node.post = head.post; // line 2
  head.post.pre = node;  // line 3
  head.post = node;      // line 4
}
```

I trying tracing the code

line1:    head->node; head->tail(original list)

line2:    head->node->tail; head->tail(original list)

line3:    ????

line4:    ????

I cannot understand line 3 and line 4, after executing line 1 and line 2, there are two double linked list (one is original double link list and another is the newly created one)? which head is line 3 is referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that head and tail are the only two nodes in the doubly linked list initially, the following is what happens... in ascii art!

Before the call:

```
                  +--------+
                  |    post|
                  |  node  |
                  |pre     |
                  +--------+

+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
|                                           |
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
+-> |    post+---------------> |    post+---+
    |  head  |                 |  tail  |
+---+pre     | <---------------+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Line 1:

```
                  +--------+
                  |    post|
                  |  node  |
       +----------+pre     |
       |          +--------+
       |
+------|------------------------------------+
|      |                                    |
|      v                                    |
|   +--+-----+                 +--------+   |
+-> |    post+---------------> |    post+---+
    |  head  |                 |  tail  |
+---+pre     | <---------------+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Line 2:

```
                  +--------+
                  |    post+---------+
                  |  node  |         |
       +----------+pre     |         |
       |          +--------+         |
       |                             |
+------|-----------------------------|------+
|      |                             |      |
|      v                             v      |
|   +--+-----+                 +-----+--+   |
+-> |    post+---------------> |    post+---+
    |  head  |                 |  tail  |
+---+pre     | <---------------+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Line 3:

```
                  +--------+
                  |    post+---------+
                  |  node  |         |
       +----------+pre     |         |
       |          +------+-+         |
       |                 ^           |
+------|-----------------|-----------|------+
|      |                 |           |      |
|      v                 |           v      |
|   +--+-----+           |     +-----+--+   |
+-> |    post+---------------> |    post+---+
    |  head  |           |     |  tail  |
+---+pre     |           +-----+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Line 4:

```
                  +--------+
                  |    post+---------+
                  |  node  |         |
       +----------+pre     |         |
       |          +-+----+-+         |
       |            ^    ^           |
+------|------------|----|-----------|------+
|      |            |    |           |      |
|      v            |    |           v      |
|   +--+-----+      |    |     +-----+--+   |
+-> |    post+------+    |     |    post+---+
    |  head  |           |     |  tail  |
+---+pre     |           +-----+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+                 +--------+   |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Final result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|   +--------+        +--------+        +--------+   |
+-> |    post+-------->    post+-------->    post+---+
    |  head  |        |  node  |        |  tail  |
+---+pre     <--------+pre     <--------+pre     | <-+
|   +--------+        +--------+        +--------+   |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 is saying that the first item in your list, should have a previous value of your new last item.

Line 4 is saying that your old last item should now actually have a next value that points to the new head.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 modifies the old second node (which is now the 3rd node). It sets the new 2nd node as its previous node.

Line 4 modifies the head to set the new node as the 2nd node.

Answer (score 1):

Initial state of the **doubly linked list**;

```
head -----------------> head.post
```

In this case, consider that **head.post** is an arbitrary node and the new node is going to be located (inserted) after **head**, and before the **head.post**.

The states of the references of `head`, `head.post` and `node` is changed gradually as below;

#### First Line

**node.pre = head;**

```
head <----------------> head.post
head <----------------- node
```

#### Second Line

**node.post = head.post;**

```
head <----------------> head.post
head <----- node -----> head.post
```

#### Third Line

**head.post.pre = node;**

```
head <----- node <----> head.post
```

#### Fourth Line

**head.post = node;**

```
head <----> node <----> head.post
```

Hope that it helps.